# problems using data.table in question template R-exams

Tags: r, data.table, r-exams

I am stuck with this question that wants to use data.table. I used dplyr successfully in other questions, so i am a bit puzzled whats going on.

````
```{r data generation, echo = FALSE, results = "hide", cache=FALSE}


library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

# data.table hack?
d <- income <- id <- it <- age <- .N <- NULL

n = 100
IT = 40
pension = 1.0
inc1 = runif(n = 1, min = 0.06, max = 0.08)
inc2 = -0.0008
alphas = runif(n,min = 0, max = 1)
epsilon = 0.2

d = data.table(expand.grid(id=1:n, it = 1:IT))
d[ , alpha := alphas[id]]
d[ , age := it + 19]
d[ , shock := rnorm(n = .N, sd = epsilon)]
d[ , income := exp(alpha + inc1 * age + inc2* age^2 + shock)]
d[, alpha := NULL]
d[, shock := NULL]
# end data generation
fwrite(d, file = "panel.csv")

questions <- solutions <- expl <- list()
type <- list()

# how many individuals do you observe?
questions[[1]] <- "how many individuals do you observe?"
solutions[[1]] <- d[ , max(id)]
type[[1]] <- "num"
expl[[1]] <- "look at the biggest id entry"
# 
# 
# # how many time periods?
questions[[2]] <- "how many time periods?"
solutions[[2]] <- d[ , max(it)]
expl[[2]] <- "look at the biggest it entry"
type[[2]] <- "num"
```


Question
========

In this question you should use the data set saved at [this link](panel.csv) for you. Please download from moodle by right-clicking and saving on your computer. I use the dataset as object `d` in my solutions.

```{r questionlist, echo = FALSE, results = "asis"}
answerlist(unlist(questions), markup = "markdown")
```


Solution
========

```{r solutionlist, echo = FALSE, results = "asis"}
answerlist(unlist(solutions),paste(unlist(expl), ".", sep = ""), markup = "markdown")
```



Meta-information
================
extype: cloze
exsolution: `r paste(solutions, collapse = "|")`
exclozetype: `r paste(type, collapse = "|")`
exname: panel
extol: 0.05
````

If i run this i get

```
> exams2html("exercises/panel/paneltest.Rmd")
Error in read_metainfo(file) : no exsolution specified
```

while executing the Rmd in the global scope returns the correct answer:

```
> answerlist(unlist(questions), markup = "markdown")
Answerlist
----------
* how many individuals do you observe?
* how many time periods?
> answerlist(unlist(solutions),paste(unlist(expl), ".", sep = ""), markup = "markdown")
Answerlist
----------
* 100. look at the biggest id entry.
* 40. look at the biggest it entry.
```

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: Thanks for raising this issue, I'm puzzled as well. If you run `xweave("datatable.Rmd")` and look at the resulting `datatable.md` file you see what is going on - but I don't understand why. You get an error in `Error in \`:=\`(alpha, alphas[id]): Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise [...]` And this error leads to `exsolution` being empty. Internally `xweave()` essentially just calls `knitr::knit()` and the `xweave()` function works fine if sourced. However, when called from withint the namespace of `exams` the error occurs. I'm not sure though what is problematic in our namespace?!

Comment: hmm, not sure whether a namespace conflict could be it - i haven't seen anything suspicious in your namespace. we'd get a method error in that case no? I had this kind of error before with data.table in Rmd. I'll ask around!

Comment: Try defining `.datatable.aware = TRUE` at start of your script. Some descriptions of its usage can be found in Importing data.table vignette.

Comment: are you using cache=TRUE? i notice it's set to false for the first chunk but not subsequent ones

Comment: both of those suggestions did not solve the issue :-(

Comment: I'm stumped too; it knits fine as a regular .Rmd -> .html. I think @Achim's first comment holds the key to the solution. FWIW I tried a paired down version where I just created `d = data.table(x=1:10)` and then `solutions[[1]] <- d[ , max(x)]`. Even then it failed, so I think R-exams is just struggling with data.table in general. OTOH, `solutions[[1]] <- max(d$x)` works.

Comment: I still have no solution but noticed that running everything in the global environment avoids the issues: `exams2html("paneltest.Rmd", envir = .GlobalEnv)`. So at least you have a workaround. Let me know if you think that this is useful enough to be turned into an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: that's a good enough workaround! good as an answer for me. thanks!